# How TeXLive understands where to place a .PDF file on installation?

Tags: texlive, tlmgr

I have a package, which I deployed to CTAN. It includes a `.sty` file and a few images in `.pdf` format. When I install this package from CTAN using `tlmgr install`, the `.pdf` images are placed into the `texmf-dist/doc/latex` directory, while I expect them to stay next to the `.sty` file, in the `texmf-dist/tex/latex` directory, because I need to include them in `.sty` using `\includegraphics{}`.

How can I instruct `tlmgr` that my `.pdf` files are required in runtime and are *not* part of the documentation?

Comment: email texlive list and ask Karl to adjust

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did and the problem was solved: https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2021-June/047175.html Thanks!